# How to log to different appenders from one Controller w/Grails & log4j

Tags: log4j, grails-2.0

I have a controller where I would like to log to different appenders based on the level.  So for examaple general usage would be written to a INFO usage.log.  Certain events I determine  should go to a WARN warning.log.

Here's a portion of my log4j config…

```
appenders {
    file name: "usageAppender",
        file: " /usr/local/logs/cs-wst/usage.log"

    file name: "warningAppender",
        file: " /usr/local/logs/cs-wst/warning.log"
}

info usageAppender: 'grails.app'
```

When I do this and run a statement like this in my controller `log.info("request method fired")` the line does show up in usage.log, but I'm having trouble getting other levels to work.  I would like to run these two statements in the controller

```
log.info("request method fired")
…
log.warn("invalid credentials")
```

And have them logged to the appropriate file.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the code below;

```
appenders {

    appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: 'dailyerrorAppender',
            threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG,
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",  // See the API for all patterns.
            fileName: "./error",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern:'%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n')
    )

    appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: 'dailywarnAppender',
            threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN,
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",  // See the API for all patterns.
            fileName: "./warn",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern:'%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n')
    )

}
environments {
    development{
        debug dailyerrorAppender:"errors", additivity: false
        warn dailywarnAppender:"warns", additivity: false
    }
    qa{
        debug dailyerrorAppender:"errors", additivity: false
        warn dailywarnAppender:"warns", additivity: false
    }
    production{
        debug dailyerrorAppender:"errors", additivity: false
        warn dailywarnAppender:"warns", additivity: false
    }
}

def errorLog = Logger.getLogger("errors")

errorLog.debug("your error messages")

def warnLog = Logger.getLogger("warns")

warnLog.warn("your warn messages")
```